# PopupDateField Listener

Tags: java, listener, vaadin7, datefield

I've got a PopupDateField with a ValueChangeListener.

Is there a way to differentiate if the Event was fired from an .setValue()-Call or an User-Input?

I want the Event to be excuted only if the user changes the value, not if it was changed by program.

---

I've made a dirty Workaround by removing the ValueChangListener before setting a new Value and adding it afterwards, but I'm thankfull for better solutions...

```
private static void setDateFieldValue(final PopupDateField dateField, Date value) {
    Collection<Property.ValueChangeListener> listeners = (Collection<Property.ValueChangeListener>)dateField.getListeners(Property.ValueChangeEvent.class);
    listeners.forEach(new Consumer<Property.ValueChangeListener>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Property.ValueChangeListener listener) {
            dateField.removeValueChangeListener(listener);
        }
    });

    dateField.setValue(value);

    listeners.forEach(new Consumer<Property.ValueChangeListener>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Property.ValueChangeListener listener) {
            dateField.addValueChangeListener(listener);
        }
    });
}
```